# checking array with previous value in array

Tags: php

I have an time array and the frequency of reading is 5 seconds

I want to check if the frequency of reading is 5 second between every element of

array

My code

```
$freq_of_reading = 5;
$res_arr = array(
    0 => array("13:53:45"),
    1 => array("13:53:50"),
    2 => array("13:53:55"),
    3 => array("13:54:00"),
    4 => array("13:54:05"),
    5 => array("13:54:10"),
    6 => array("13:54:15"),
    7 => array("13:54:20"),
    8 => array("13:54:25"),
    9 => array("13:54:30"),
);


try {
    $u = 0;
    foreach ($res_arr as $key => $item) {
        // if(strtotime($item))
        //Logic here 
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $exp = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, what result are you currently getting, and what is the desired result?  You haven't given us enough information to help you.

Comment: so... `if ((arr[i] - arr[i-1]) > 5 seconds)) { Ooops! }`

Comment: It seems that he want to check if the frequency of reading is correct all over the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($res_arr) - 1; $i++)
{
    if(strtotime($res_arr[$i + 1][0]) - strtotime($res_arr[$i][0]) != $freq_of_reading)
    {
        echo "Element $i differs from the next one more than $freq_of_reading s";
        exit;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$count = count($res_arr);
for($i=0;$i<$count$i++)
    {
        $number = intval(substr($res_arr[$i], -2));

        $number1 = substr(($res_arr[$i+1], -2));
        if(($number1-$number) == 5)
        {
          echo "true";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's in a `try`, but:

```
$freq_of_reading = 5;
$previous = 0;

foreach($res_arr as $item) {
    $time = strtotime($item[0]);
    if($time - $freq_of_reading == $previous) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    $previous = $time;
}
```